# Will grass grow from just a dirt field?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am currently playing a survival map called [SkyBlock](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/600254-surv-skyblock/) and I removed all my grass blocks but now I need to have grass. So am I now screwed or will grass grow on the dirt field?

Comment: you removed _all_ of your grass blocks??

Comment: bad idea removing all the grass blocks

Comment: That is one of the classic ways to lose a game of SkyBlock.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Grass only spreads from grass blocks. If your map contains no grass blocks, it never will (unless you place them in creative mode, or otherwise hack them in). Bonemeal will not cause dirt blocks to grow grass, they will only cause tall grass (and flowers) to grow on grass blocks.

Answer (score 2):

Grass grows from other grass blocks touching it.. If you have at least one grass block on it, the grass will eventually spread.

Comment: How does this answer differ from the one by **fredley** posted 5 months earlier?

Answer (score -4):

You can get a shovel with the "Silk Touch" enchantment and go to the main land!

Comment: While this is a possibility, isn't going to the mainland explicitly disallowed in the instructions?

Comment: Flying around in creative, I didn't _see_ a mainland. There was a pretty good radius of void.